# How do I output vertex group from geometry nodes 3.0

Tags: geometry-nodes

If I output some texture from the geometry node system how can I use it as a vertex group? (I am trying to apply it as a pin group into a cloth modifier that is applied right after the geometry nodes modifier

[image]

Comment: not quite. I've seen this one, so I converted my output into float and I even can use it in another GN as mantioned. But I just can't make it work as a vertex group. Perhaps I have to assign this map to existing vertex group first?

Comment: I think in this case you do have to first create the VG on the mesh